# cordova/phonegap image upload to Amazon s3

Tags: android, cordova, amazon-s3, phonegap-build

I am trying to upload an image (as base64 format) from phone gap application to amazon s3. The image is uploaded successfully, but it's displayed as boxes when I try to view the image in Amazon server. I used the below link for my reference.

[Uploading image to S3 using phonegap, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844586/uploading-image-to-s3-using-phonegap-how-to)

I also tried to upload the image (as imageURI) using the below link, but it throws an error Body.params is required

https://github.com/ccoenraets/phonegap-s3-upload/blob/master/client/phonegap-s3-upload/www/app.js

Please find the snippets of code,

```
// take picture
var options =   {
          quality: 75,
          targetWidth: 320,
          targetHeight: 320,
          destinationType: 1, // 0 = base 64, 1 = imageURI
          sourceType: 1,      // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album
          encodingType: 0     // 0=JPG 1=PNG
      };
    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess,onFail,options);


    ---------
uploading the image

var imageData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ $scope.lastPhoto;
         var params = {
              Key: 'test5.jpg', // for testing purpose 
              Body: imageData, // base64 data
              ContentEncoding: 'base64',
              ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
            };
            var fileName = "" + (new Date()).getTime() + ".jpg"; 
            console.log ('data params' + params.Body);
            bucket.upload(params, function(err, data){
              $scope.hide($ionicLoading);
              var result = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY...';
              var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                 title: 'Amazon  Confirmation',
                 template: 'Result : ' + result
              });
```

Comment: Can you open the image URL in a browser? If you try that and it still shows as a box, the image my be corrupt.

Comment: It works fine in the browser. Just FYI.. I am testing on Android browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this link [how to save canvas data to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867534/how-to-save-canvas-data-to-file/5971674#5971674)

var data = img.replace(/^data:image/\w+;base64,/, "");

Answer (score 0):

AWS.config.update({

```
            accessKeyId : 'your-ACCESSKEYID',
            secretAccessKey : 'SECRETACCESSKEY'


       });
```

$cordovaCapture.captureVideo().then(function(videoData) {

```
          $scope.file=videoData[0].name;




             var first='file:/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/';

             $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(first,$scope.file)
                  .then(function (success) {

                var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: { Bucket: 'your-bucket-name' }});

                  var params = {Key: videoData[0].name, ContentEncoding: 'base64', ContentType: 'video/mp4; charset=UTF-8' , Body: success};

                  bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
                    $scope.uploading = true;
                    $scope.progress = parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%';
                    console.log("Uploaded :: " + $scope.progress );         
                    $scope.$apply();
                  }).send(function(err, data) {
                    $scope.uploading = false;
                    /*$scope.images.push(data.Location);*/

                    console.log(data.Location);
                    $scope.$apply();
                  });


                  }, function (error) {

                  console.log("==========error==========");
                  console.log(error);
                  })


            })

      }
```